# proof that inf(-A)=-sup(A)

Tags: real-analysis

If A is nonempty and has an upper bound proof that inf(-A)=-sup(A).
And if A has a lower bound sup(-A)=-inf(A).
I've already shown that -A has lower bound for first case and has an upper bound for second.